# Any way to deform one object around another on one edge only?

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap, surface-deform, lattice, clipping

I'm new to Blender so I apologize if this is something that is either super easy or clearly impossible. I've tried looking for solutions and a couple have come close to what I want to accomplish, but it's not exactly what I want.

Here's what I want to do (I'll try to be as clear as possible). I have two separate objects:

[image: The two objects that need to go together (don't ask me what they are)]

I want to put the pyramid-like object onto the cylinder object in the direction of the arrow and have it appear as though both objects are actually one, per the previous screenshot. However, the two objects are completely different in terms of shape and angle so of course the bottom of the edges go through the top of the cylinder as seen below:

[image: This is what the final result should look like, but with needed edits]

Now, that is the final position that I want the pyramid to be at and in most cases the clipping at the bottom would be fine. However, for my specific purposes I can't have clipping. So, I was wondering if it is possible in Blender to deform ONLY the bottom edges of the pyramid object so that they conform to the shape of the top part of that cylinder object?

I've tried a few different things based on my research, but nothing has achieved exactly what I want (probably for good reason since my use-case is so specific and in most other cases, the clipping would be fine). The closest I ever got was using a lattice and adding a shrinkwrap modifier to it. However, that ended up warping the whole object rather than just the bottom edges as seen below:

[image: Close, but not exactly...]

So, is what I am trying to do even possible without having to manually edit each vertex (which is what I first tried, but it's extremely tedious and I have many more objects I would need to do this too and I figured there must be a quicker way) and if so, how do I go about accomplishing it? If there is no way, then so be it. I just wanted to try saving some time and effort.

Also, just in case this matters, there is no animation or anything that will be applied to these objects. This will all purely be static.

Regardless of the outcome, thank you very much in advance for helping me out with this. If more details are required, I will be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it possible to automatically and cleanly connect two meshes ?**

As far as I know, no you can't really. Geometries that don't have the same amount of vertices (*resolution* if you prefer) is a complex topic, that I don't know well. Here is a quick overview of what I would suggest. Keep in mind nothing below is an absolute rule.

**Does it matter to have clean geometry ?**

Not always !

---

#### Do you need as much vertices ?

Your models are quite heavy on the vertex count. Why do you have multiple vertices on the same flat plane ? If you are working your mesh in *Edit Mode*, you should first simplify it *as much as possible*.

Do you intend on using *Subdivision Surface* ? Or will your models stay on a more low-poly style ? You should answer these questions for yourself first.

#### Do you *need* the two parts to be connected ?

In some cases, this doesn't matter at all (not an exhaustive list) :

- No transparency/translucency
- No intend of using *Subdivision Surface*
- No intend of using *Bevel*

If one of these points is yes, you probably need to have them connected. Otherwise, you totally can just have the base of your triangular shape inside the other mesh.

#### Do you need to have clean geometry ?

If you are using modifier to further change the geometry, like *Bevel* or *Subdivision Surface*, a bad geometry is likely to create artifacts with this kind of modifiers.

You may still merge them at your own risk (meaning geometry could get ugly) with *Boolean* modifiers. Here is an example of *Boolean* modifier set to *Union*. On the left side are the 2 objects before applying the modifier, right side is after applying.

[image: Before and after boolean union]

You may think this is *clean* geometry, but don't be fooled ! For exemple a face with more than 4 vertices is likely to generate artifacts when combining with other operations.

You could also apply a boolean operation, then tweak a little bit the mesh manually to be more clean. If you add a modifier (without *applying* it), you'll quickly see the regions that react badly and need rework.

To summarize by priority :

1. Let your meshes be separate
2. If not possible, then try a ugly way like *Boolean* operations
3. If not possible, then merge them by hand

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first thing you have to do is make sure the bottom vertices of the cone object and top vertices of the cylinder object are equal. And then try to snap the vertices of  the first object into the second

i dont know  this is what you are asking  but hope it works